# How to submit two separate forms with one button with Flask request

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, forms, flask

I have two forms in separate regions of my webpage, this is an example with them just next to each other.

```
<form action="" class="" method="post">
          <input type="text" class="form_control" placeholder="email" name="email" value="{{request.form.email}}">
          <input type="password" class="" placeholder="password" name="password" value="{{request.form.password}}">

          <form action="" class="" method="post">
              <input type="text" class="form_control" placeholder="email" name="email2" value="{{request.form.email2}}">
              <input type="password" class="" placeholder="password" name="password2" value="{{request.form.password2}}">
              <input class="" type="submit" name="btn" value="login">
      </form>
```

Does Flask request allow me to submit both of these forms with the one button in the second form, or is the only way to do this via AJAX?

Comment: Yes you will need to use Ajax requests if you want to do two actions with one submission. A submit button only submits the form that it is attached too.

Comment: Browser can only send one form through default process. Back end is not the constraint

Comment: In HTML 5 you can associate form elements that are outside of the form declaration. You give the main form an id i.e. <from id=login> and elements that are outside of this use <input type=text form=login>

Comment: Thanks Jeff! I had no idea that had been added to HTML5 and it certainly simplifies things - thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, you cannot have forms embedded in another form

Comment: Ah cheers, whoops I accidentally forget the extra /form when I made the example.